# Java threads on javafx animation and A* path finding

Tags: java, multithreading, animation, javafx, path-finding

Forgive the possibly simple question, but I am struggling to figure out how and when to use a thread when animating sprites in javafx.

I am creating an application that has obstacles and animals on a 2D map. I have an algorithm inside the animal class that uses A* path finding to get a list of nodes that will take it to a target. The method returns an ArrayList containing the path.
I then aim to have a method that animates the animal from its start position to the target using the List got from the pathfinding. However I am very unsure on how to use threads to do this. there will always be more than one animal and i want them all to be constantly moving around.

I have thought that I could use a thread to call update periodically that will then create a thread per animal and move it a pixel at a time to its location, but then i would have to call the find path function each time.

I am struggling to think on how to synchronise everything.
Is there a standard way of managing this?

Comment: Can you just use the [animation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm#JFXTE149)? Perhaps a combination of [`TranslateTransition`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) and/or [`PathTransition`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html) in a [`SequentialTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html). That way you would not have to manage any threads at all; the API takes care of all the threading for you.

Comment: Or he could use your awesome AnimationTimerTest as inspiration, like I have :D https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842